# 'Type mismatch' error for Index Match

Tags: excel, vba

Inaugural post so apologies if format wrong (let me know).  Thanks in advance for any help.

Attempting to find equivalent in VBA for the following Excel formula:

```
=INDEX([OPEN2.xlsx]Sheet1!$AH$1:$AH$35596,
MATCH(1,
(F2=[OPEN2.xlsx]Sheet1!$G$1:$G$35596)*
(G2=[OPEN2.xlsx]Sheet1!$I$1:$I$35596)*
(Q2=[OPEN2.xlsx]Sheet1!$V$1:$V$35596)*
(R2=[OPEN2.xlsx]Sheet1!$W$1:$W$35596)*
(S2=[OPEN2.xlsx]Sheet1!$X$1:$X$35596)*
(T2=[OPEN2.xlsx]Sheet1!$Y$1:$Y$35596)
,0))
```

I tried the below (inside a loop, of course) but receive 'type mismatch' error.  I had dimmed each variable below 'as range' and declared each range (e.g. 'Set rmtd = range("g1:g35596")').

Should I have declared as another variable type?  I am probably doing something basic wrong - how do I make the data compatible/comparable below so that I don't receive 'type mismatch'?

```
Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> ""
ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(rmmxref, _
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, _
(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -16) = rmtd) * _
(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -15) = rmvd) * _
(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6) = rmsnoti) * _
(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5) = rmsccy) * _
(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4) = rmbnoti) * _
(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3) = rmbccy) * _
(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -18) = rmcp), _
0))
     ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
  Loop
```

Comment: You can't multiply arrays like that in VBA. The simplest solution is to use Evaluate and pass the formula string to it.

Comment: Thanks, Rory!  Will try that and let you know solution if I get it to work.

Comment: How would I evaluate those 7 conditions in one go so that the number "1" is returned if all 7 are located in any ONE row?  Struggling to find the right way to write this.  Thanks

Comment: Actually, your formula is longer than the 255 character limit for Evaluate. Can you not simply put the formula into the cells then replace it with its value?

Comment: Hi Rory.  Many thanks for another suggestion.  I tried to use the raw formula and then use its output but I encountered two issues 
(i) I could not find syntax to use this Excel formula in VBA and get it to work 
(ii) Linked to point 1 I guess - the formula requires the use of a variable value, so I was unable to get anything to work.

Comment: I eventually got the output I desired in VBA by using a 'For Next' loop and combining a number of 'IF' statements. 

Thank you again for your suggestions though :) @Rory

Comment: Tried to paste the code in here but it's too long